# Optimizations turned off improved performance?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Out team ran into an interesting problem that we cannot explain. One of our users complained that running the code on his machine was slow.  We investigate the issue and were able to replicate the issue on a VM.

Just a note here: The code is divided up into different assemblies.  The main app is the EXE and the rest of the program is in assembly DLLs that are their own projects.

First we tested the database.  Sometimes the production database can be slower than the dev database due to load.  This did not make any appreciable difference.  In both cases launching the code required about 15 seconds.  SLOW AS ....!  The designer file has 4400 lines of code.

we tried ngen, gac and a number of other attempts to explain the slowness but nothing worked.

After a number of different tests our lead developer finally found the problem.  When we deployed the Release version to the VM, it was SLOW (15 seconds to load the form).  When we deployed the DEBUG version to the VM it was FAST (under 5 seconds to load the form).  After further investigation we found that when we disabled the optimizations (Double Click My Project in the vb.net project folder, select Compile and then on Advanced Compile Options, **uncheck** the Enable Optimizations) the code was faster than when the optimizations were on.  We confirmed that the code slowdown occurs in all cases during the IntializeComponent event.

However... just to throw in a big wrinkle. We have the ANTS performance profiler installed on our dev machines and when we profile the code runs in 3.1 seconds with the optimizations off.

Add yet another wrinkle... when the InitializeComponent code is run in the debugger, with the optimizations turned on the code runs in 891ms.  The exact same code with the optimizations turn on running outside of visual studio on the SAME development machine the code runs in 11,796ms.

The second time the same code is run, without shutting down the application, the code runs equally fast with the optimizations on or off the results are sub 100ms for both (debug/outside visual studio)

All operating systems are running windows 7 (x64) and the code base is compiled for AnyCPU and all the test machines have framework 4.5 installed (same as dev machines) but the projects are built against framework 4.0 (for XP compatibility purposes).

If anyone out there has had any experience with something like this then we would appreciate it.  Obviously we are stumped and more than a bit mystified by this.  There are people that claim their release code runs slower than their debug code on the internet but most of the replies are in the vein of "Thats odd" but no one seems to know.  Our off the cuff thinking is that this is a problem with the .NET framework somehow.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Did you look at the bug report on Microsoft Connect?  I think the issue is verified at this point.  If you insist I can probably gin something together but the issue is occurring in proprietary source code that I cannot release.  Also note that it ONLY occurs in 64bit compilations running on Windows 7 with the framework 4.5.1 installed.  If it occurs on Vista, I would not know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what we have found to date the following seems to be the issue.  The JIT of the .NET code in the InitializeComponent is what takes the time.  We have done a bunch of "old school" profiling and we have confirmed that the delay occurs BEFORE the InitializeComponent event is even called.  Once the code actually gets into the subroutine it runs in just a second or two (which is what we would think to be normal for such a complex form).

Turns out the issue has been reported to Microsoft but there is not much visibility on this so if you coders out there can replicate our issue please light a fire under MS by logging into your MS accounts and marking the issue as replicated by you (as long as you can replicate it).
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/824721/64bit-jit-compiler-works-very-slow-when-initializecomponent-method-is-processed

Workaround:
Obviously you can turn the optimizations off in the compiler for a project as well, but if you want to leave them on and just target specific forms, the following also works.

If you enter the Designer File and put this line above the InitializeComponent

Turns out that Microsoft is creating a new JIT.  Called RyuJIT.  However, to get this awesome new set of bugs you must upgrade to windows 8.1!

Comment: That is interesting.. given that you tried NGEN'ing it and it was still slow.

Comment: Thats what we thought too.  The ngen made very little difference.  However once we found the connect article everything started to make sense.  I am trying to gin up an example for Dour High Arch that demonstrates this as I cannot release the code that we have seen this in.  Hopefully I can replicate it.